# What is the difference between ordered by inclusion and ordered by containment?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

I found this in a textbook, and the definition for ordered by containment and ordered by inclusion looks the same, except the subseteq is facing a different direction which doesn't really change anything. Can someone help me understand the difference between the definitions? Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the change in the direction of $\subseteq$ change the definition of the order?

Comment: Changing $\subseteq$ to $\supseteq$ **does** really change something.

Comment: @FShrike what does it change? can you please expand on it?

Comment: It changes because you’re using a different order. That’s all, that’s the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn’t a huge difference between the two scenarios. As you realise, swapping from $\subseteq$ to $\supseteq$ reverses the direction of the partial order. If you’re only considering power sets, then that doesn’t change the structure of your poset - those posets are isomorphic. But they are different posets, in that e.g. $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$ has a maximum element as a sub-poset of one of those posets but not of the other.